# How to avoid shifting a small box that ends a paragraph to a position on its own at the beginning of the next line?

Tags: html, css

I need a small box, like this ■, at the end of a paragraph, 10px wide and starting 10px after the final full stop. My CSS is as follows:

**CSS**

```
.black-square {width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:#000;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px; }
```

This works fine, so long as the paragraph's last sentence does not end at or very close to the end of a line, when the square gets shifted to a position on its own on the next line, indented by 10px.

How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the black box to 'stick' to the last word of the paragraph and not drop to it's own new line:

1) Create a span element immediately after the last word of the paragraph containing a simple non breaking space `nbsp;` and the black box.

2) Disable wrapping between the `nbsp;` and box with: `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
.black-square {
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:#000;
  display:inline-block;
  }
  
.stick {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>
Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar<span class="stick">&nbsp;<span class="black-square"></span></span>
</p>
```

**[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/NvoKBr)** - (Resize to see the black box wrap with the last word)

### Note:

The spec in [CSS text module level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-4/#propdef-wrap-before) describes a new property `wrap-before`.

In the future - when this property will be implemented, and assuming markup like:

```
<p>
Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar <span class="black-square"></span>
</p>
```

we'll be able to achieve the above behaviour simply with:

```
.black-square {
  wrap-before: avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `margin-left` property from your CSS and instead use 2 or 3 non-breaking space entities (`&nbsp;`) in your HTML code.

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ashzjt0r/1/

Comment: Would it be possible to use `.black-square::before { content: "<something>" }` instead of editing the HTML? What value would work here to accomplish this?

Comment: Pseudo classes cannot be used to insert HTML content or entities. 

I wouldn't really recommend doing this in most cases, but it is *possible* to use the `before` pseudo-class (or pseudo-element) to insert a transparent spacer image as a "shim."

Comment: Thanks, but using `&nbsp;`s can still push the square to the next line on its own, albeit not indented.

Comment: I thought that your question was about "when the square gets shifted to a position on its own on the next line, indented by 10px." If you want to prevent wrapping of the entire paragraph, then use `white-space: nowrap;` on your paragraph element, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add the class to the paragraph instead of adding markup (if that's what you're currently doing)...

```
<p class='black-square'>this is a test and a test is all that it is and it will never be anything more (except maybe a waste of time)</p>
```

and adding the square in the CSS which isn't changed much

```
.black-square::after {
  content: "";
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:#000;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kwgtncLr/2/

Comment: As an aside I've always used a single colon for :after but it seems pretty common to use the double ::after. Initial investigation indicates the double colon is appropriate in this case due to it being used to select a psuedo-_element_ though there doesn't seem to much of a case for me to break my habits :)

Comment: Thanks, but this still allows the square to be pushed down to a line on its own at certain screen widths. I couldn't get that to happen at JSFiddle with your text, owing to the specific collection of words it contains, but it happens if the word "waste" is replaced with "big lot".

Comment: Ah I see that. It really might be a big waste of time! anyway - it seems to help if you take out the `margin-left` and add `position: relative; left: 10px;` https://jsfiddle.net/kwgtncLr/2/ updated in answer.

Comment: I thought that was going to work, but it can still push the square to a position on its own on the next line, e.g. with the text "a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a".